# How to sample a SRV when enable msaa x4?DirectX11

Tags: directx-11, msaa

I'm learning dx11 from Introduction_to_3D_Game_Programming_with_Directx_11.
Everything is ok without msaa. When I enable it, my .fx and C++ codes will not work well.
Do someone experienced it too and how to deal with this situation?

Before Codes:

```
Texture2D gTexture1;
float4 BLEND_PS(VertexOut_SV pin) :SV_TARGET
{
    float4 texColor = float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    texColor = gTexture1.Sample(SamAnisotropic, pin.Tex);
    return texColor;
}
```

because I can't bind a texture created with msaa to a texture2D,so I take msaa ON whenever.

After codes:

```
Texture2DMS<float4> gTexture1;
float4 BLEND_PS(VertexOut_SV pin) :SV_TARGET
{
    float4 texColor = float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    texColor = gTexture1.Load(int2(pin.Tex.x*1400, pin.Tex.y*900), 0);
    return texColor;
}
```

But the texColor is not right pixel I want.How to sample an SRV with msaa?
How to convert an UAV without msaa into a SRV with msaa?

And how to enable and disable msaa in C++ game codes with corresponding hlsl codes?
Do I have to keep different hlsl for each other?

Comment: I don't understand what you are using MSAA for here. Typically you'd create an MSAA render target, then resolve to a non-MSAA texture as part of presenting. What are you trying to do with an MSAA texture here?

Comment: Hello,CW. Thank you at first.Maybe I should ask :how to enable MSAA in a dx11 demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 'standard' MSAA use, you do the following:

1. When creating your swap chain and render traget view, set `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC.SampleDesc.Count` or  `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1.SampleDesc.Count` to 2, 4, 8, etc.
2. When creating your depth buffer/stencil, you need to use the same sample count for `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC.SampleDesc.Count`.
3. When creating your render target view, you need to use `D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS` (or pass `nullptr` for the view description so it matches the resource exactly)
4. When creating your depth buffer/stencil view, you need to use `D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS` (or pass `nullptr` for the view description so it matches the resource exactly)
5. When rendering, you need to use a rasterizer state with `D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC.MultisampleEnable` set to TRUE.

See also the [Simple rendering](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Simple-rendering) tutorial for [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK)

## Sample count

Depending on the Direct3D feature level, some MSAA sample counts are required for particular render target formats. Use can use `CheckFormatSupport` to verify render target format supports MSAA:

```
UINT formatSupport = 0;
if (FAILED(device->CheckFormatSupport(m_backBufferFormat, &formatSupport)))
{
    throw std::exception("CheckFormatSupport");
}

UINT flags = D3D11_FORMAT_SUPPORT_MULTISAMPLE_RESOLVE
     | D3D11_FORMAT_SUPPORT_MULTISAMPLE_RENDERTARGET;

if ( (formatSupport & flags) != flags )
{
    // error
}
```

You then use `CheckMultisampleQualityLevels` to verify the sample count is supported. This code finds the highest supported MSAA level count for a particular format:

```
for (m_sampleCount = D3D11_MAX_MULTISAMPLE_SAMPLE_COUNT;
    m_sampleCount > 1; m_sampleCount--)
{
    UINT levels = 0;
    if (FAILED(device->CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(m_backBufferFormat,
            m_sampleCount, &levels)))
        continue;

    if ( levels > 0)
        break;
}

if (m_sampleCount < 2)
{
    // error
}
```

> You can also validate the depth/stencil format you want to use supports `D3D11_FORMAT_SUPPORT_DEPTH_STENCIL | D3D11_FORMAT_SUPPORT_MULTISAMPLE_RENDERTARGET`.

## Flip Style modes

The technique above only works for the older "bit-blt" style flip modes  `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD` or `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_SEQUENTIAL`. For UWP and DirectX 12 you are required to use `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL` or `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD` which will fail if you attempt to create a back buffer with a SampleCount > 1.

In this case, you create the backbuffer with a SampleCount of 1, and create your own MSAA Render Target 2D texture. You have your Render Target View point to your MSAA render target, and before you `Present` you call `ResolveSubresource` from your MSAA render target to the backbufffer. This is exactly the same thing that DXGI did for you 'behind the scenes' with the older flip models.

> For gamma-correct rendering (aka when you use a backbuffer format ending in `_SRGB`), the newer flip styles require that you use the non-SRGB equivalent for the backbuffer format or the swapchain create will fail. You set the SRGB format on the render target view instead.

Comment: Thank you! It really works.if (m_bEnable4xMsaa)
   {
    m_pD3dImmediateContext->ResolveSubresource(m_pOffScreenTex, 0, m_pTempBackBufferRT, 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM);
   }
   else
   {
    m_pD3dImmediateContext->CopyResource(m_pOffScreenTex,m_pTempBackBufferRT);
   }

Comment: I feel shamed for my cnEnlish.. MS's demo is very useful